ov2640 pclk frequency
For a project I'm working with ov2640 camera, I want to use it in normal mode to capture an image.
the size is 128x128 and I want to get it in rgb565 format not compressed.
I used the registers set given in the software application note, rgb565 settings (13.2 page 30).
I understood how to change resolution, but for my project I need to have pclk frequency very low (order of magnitude : 100kHz). I use register CLKRC and R_DVP_SP to divide pclk.

CLKRC : 0x03 so xvclk is divided by 4
R_DVP_SP : 0x40 so pclk is divided by 64

When I do that, I receive the good amount of pixel per line, but I don't receive enough lines.
I'm trying to understand the reason, in the register set given by Omnivision, a lot of register they use are reserved so I don't know if it is linked to my problem.
I did some tests, when pclk frequency is high (by that i mean we receive enough line), href period is constant (I call it Tref) and dividing pclk frequency increase the duration where href indicate valid pixel (the duty cycle increase), but if we divid too much href period increase and the duty cycle stay constant at around 94% and we receive less lines. I feel like vsync stay at 1 (it means i is valid in my case) for a 128xTref so if href period increase the frame end before receiving enough lines.
